# PHP/Symfony2: Call methods "dynamically"

Tags: php, symfony

I have a questionnaire that my users need to fill in. I have a questionnaire entity with properties $question1, $question2, $question3, etc. With corresponding methods getQuestion1(), setQuestion1(), etc.

I receive the questions in my controller function in an array that look like this:

`$questions = array("1" => 'Answer to question 1', "2" => 'Answer to question 2',...);`

Is there a way that I can call the corresonding set method "dynamically" in a loop so that I don't have to run type out everything?

Something like:

```
foreach ($questions as $key => $question)
{
    $questionnaire->setQuestion.$key($question);
}
```

I know that the above won't work, but is there SOME way that I can do it this way, as there are about 100 questions and I really don't want to type it all out. Is also makes the controller function more generic so that if questions get added/removed later on then I do not have to make any changes to the controller function.

Comment: `call_user_func(array($questionnaire, 'setQuestion'.$key), $question);`

Comment: Avoid using "magic", just because it's possible, doesn't mean it's a good idea to use. I recommend to use a parameterbag, possibly one like: http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach from another angle:

How about crating just another *entity* called `Question`? You could add a `1:n` relation between your `Questionnaire` and your `Question`. The *entity* would look something like this:

```
class Question {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $answer;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Questionnaire")
     */
    private $questionnaire;
}
```

On the other side the `Questionnaire` entity:

```
class Questionnaire {    
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Question")
     */
    private $questions;

    public function getQuestions()
    {
        return $this->questions;
    }
}
```

Now you can *iterate* over all `Questions` of a `Questionnaire` with a simple `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($questionnaire->getQuestions() as $question)  {
//...
```

This would give you the advantage that you can simply **add**, **remove** and **change** questions without messing with your *controller* or *form type* code.

#### Edit:

In order to make this work with your *form* you should change it to this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
  $this->add(
    'question',
    'entity',
    array(
      'class' => 'Question'
      // any more options you want...
    )
  );      
  // ...
```

And in your *controller* call it like this:

```
$questionnaire = new Questionnaire();
$questionnaire->addQuestion(/* ... */);

$this->createForm(new QuestionnaireType(), $questionnaire);
//...
```

As a *template* you could use something like this:

```
{% for question in form.questions %}
     {{ form_widget(question) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The questions come to controller from users via form. How would you assign the questions to the entity that you are suggesting?

Comment: You obviously need to change the form type. I added some quick examples.

Comment: I accepted this answer as it is the most plausible. However, in practice this method is also flawed. In order to do it this way, you would need three entities. Questionnaire, Questions linked to a questionnaire and Answers linked to a Question and a User, in order to determine who answered what for which question. I did not want to go this overly extended route and ended up saving each question manunally as `$questionnaire->setQuestion1($data['questions'][1]);`

Answer (score -1):

```
$method = 'question' . $key;
$questionnaire->$method();
```